# Sharing content.txt data between multiple Fitnesse tests

Tags: java, fitnesse

I'm trying to use one content.txt file between two Fixture tests. An intermediate class, TestUtility, gets the data from a content.txt file, and Two fixture tests call that utility class. However, I'm getting a NullPointerException from getText. I think Fitnesse doesn't accept an intermediate test file. 
Does anyone know how I could make this work?

```
public class TestUtility  extends TableFixture { 
       @BeforeClass
        public void setup()  {
            System.out.println("in setup");
            cellR0C0 = getText(0,0);
            cellR1C0 = getText(1,0);
            cellR2C0 = getText(2,0);
            cellR0C1 = new Double(getInt(0,1));
            cellR1C1 = new Double(getInt(1,1));
           cellR2C1 = new Double(getInt(2,1));

    /**
     *
     * @param fitnessRows
     */
    public void showResults(int fitnessRows){

    }
}//end class TestUtility  

public class MyTestFixture {
        /**
         *
         * @param fitnessRows
         */
         public void showResults(int fitnessRows){
            TestUtility testUtility = new TestUtility()
            testUtility.setUp();
            testUTility.restOfTest()
        }
   }

content.txt
#!|TestUtility|
!|fitnesse.fixtures.TestUtility|
|ABCDE101|200|
|ABCDE102|300|
|ABCDE103|400|
```

Comment: You should let us see the code, maybe the community can help you.

Comment: Where do you use MyTestFixture? Your question mentions UtilityTest but you showed code for TestUtility - why?

Comment: I fixed that. TestUtility is in fitnesse.fixtures with MyTestFixture, under src\test\java\fitnesse\fixtures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a fixture like `TestUtility` is created by the FitNesse test engine, it is initialized by FitNesse to let you access information from the test page with methods like `getText`.  When you create a fixture with `new`, this information is not initialized and calling `getText` will fail, as you saw.

If you want to use information from a fixture in another class, you can put the information into static fields so you can then use it in another class without creating a new instance with `new`.

Comment: Do you mean make cellR0C0 and setup static, and call the method like 
TestUtility.setUp()?

Comment: Yes, make cellR0C0 static.  But you can't call setUp from another fixture, because getText can only be called when TestUtility is executed by FitNesse on a test page.

Comment: I got input from the fixture using getText, then passed the input to the Utility class. It looks like getText and right()/wrong() should be called from the fixture.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [!include](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteWidgetTests.TestIncludeCollapsed) markup to include page into the other.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a SetUp..

Use either SetUp or SuiteSetUp